# remove objects with a specific `key: value` from an array

Tags: lodash

I have an array of object and need to use lodash to remove some of those objects with a specific key: value, for instance:

```
[
{id:1,b:22},
{id:2,b:44},
{id:3,b:56},
{id:4,b:-29}
]
```

I need to remove all object with id of 1 and 3.

i  know the way below but was wondering if there is a shorter way:

```
    var array = [
    {id:1,b:22},
    {id:2,b:44},
    {id:3,b:56},
    {id:4,b:-29}
    ];

 _.remove(array, function(n) {
  return _.includes([ 1,3 ], n.id);
});
```

Comment: Do you really need to mutate the object? it's usually a better idea to work with immutable data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**`pullAllBy`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pullAll) and provide the elements to be removed as the 2nd parameter.

```js
let data = [{id:1,b:22},{id:2,b:44},{id:3,b:56},{id:4,b:-29}]

const result = _.pullAllBy(data, [{id:1},{id:3}], 'id')
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this method **mutates** the array. If you do not want that use [_.differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#differenceBy)

Using ES6 and arrow functions + `filter` to get the values and not mutate the array will also get you somewhat of a short version:

```js
let data = [{ id: 1, b: 22 }, { id: 2, b: 44 }, { id: 3, b: 56 }, { id: 4, b: -29 }]

const result = data.filter(x => ![1,3].includes(x.id))
console.log(result)
```